# htaccess - Redirect after several non-R=301 preparing rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How to reduce the number of 301 Redirects on my website.

There are several instructions:

```
RewriteRule 11 12 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule 21 22 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule 31 32 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule 41 42 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

I want to do it like this:

```
RewriteRule 11 12 [QSA,E=RCODE:301]
RewriteRule 21 22 [QSA,E=RCODE:301]
RewriteRule 31 32 [QSA,E=RCODE:301]
RewriteRule 41 42 [QSA,E=RCODE:301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:RCODE} =301
RewriteRule . - [R=301,L,QSA]
```

What should the last `RewriteRule` be? Redirecting from `.` to `-` is not changing the original URL!

Comment: Is the first block of directives intended to be working code? (Presumably `RewriteBase` is defined somewhere if it is?) Because this wouldn't result in multiple redirects anyway, since it would replace the entire URL-path with `12` or `22`, etc. There wouldn't be a need for any more redirects? Or, are you trying to do a search and replace all occurances style redirect? (But that is not what the code does.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What should the last `RewriteRule` be?

Since the URL-path (that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against) is updated as the preceding `RewriteRule` directives are processed, you can capture the current URL-path and use that in the *substitution*. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Using a single `-` (hyphen) in the *substitution* is for "pass-through", when the URL does not change (as you have found).

A working example:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule 11 12 [E=RCODE:302]
RewriteRule 21 22 [E=RCODE:302]
RewriteRule 31 32 [E=RCODE:302]
RewriteRule 41 42 [E=RCODE:302]

RewriteCond %{ENV:RCODE} !^$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1 [R=${ENV:RCODE},L]
```

This uses whatever code (301, 302, 303, etc.) has been set by the preceding directives and only processes the final rewrite if a code has been set.

(Using 302 - temporary - redirects to test is beneficial to avoid caching problems.)

---

However, this is a "very hypothetical" example. In this case, you would get the same result, with less code, by simply removing the `L` flags in your first example. HOWEVER, your first example - with the `L` flags - is the best (most efficient) approach in this "very hypothetical" example! (Since, in this example, there is only ever at most 1 redirect and the `L` flag prevents the following directives from being unnecessarily processed.)

So, with the limited amount of information in the question, it doesn't make much sense to do it this way. If you were to describe the problem in natural language first then there may be a better way to solve this. As it stands, it looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

If the URL pattern is really as you post it (11 => 12; 21 => 22) , you can do the following:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(\d)1$ $12 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

So the first digit stays the same but if the second one is `1` we will redirect to a destination were the second one is `2`.